# How to scale UIImage using width and keep ratio

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImage` that is much smaller than the `UIImageView` I am applying it too, I would like to know how to scale the `UIImage` to fit the width of the `UIImageView` but keep the width x height ratio of the original small image.

This is what my code looks like pre any sort of scaling

```
playerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 222.0, self.playerView.frame.size.width-20, 245.0)];
playerImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;
UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"placeHolderVault.png"];
[playerImageView setImage:placeholderImage];
```

Comment: Isn't `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` good enough for your need ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the proper `contentMode`.

```
playerImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```